# How to get inserted id of pivot when I use attach() in Laravel 5.6 (Eloquent)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have this tables: **users**, **programs** and **users_programs** (*pivot*)

I use this sentence to relate users with programs (Many to Many)

```
$user->programs()->attach($program);
```

I want to get id to pivot table *users_programs*, it's posible? How I return id when save a row?

Thanks

Comment: Basically it is not recommended to use ID in your pivot tables because pivot tables are designed to store huge amount of data so if you use ID in your pivot table you can break `unsigned integer` max length.

Comment: You can fetch your data like this: `User::find($userID)->programs()->get()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pivot tables don't have an increment id field in the realm of `Eloquent`.

If you want to get a specific program for a user in the pivot table, you can use something like the following approach as an example:

```
$user->programs()->attach($program->id);
$user = $user->fresh();
$userProgram  = $user->programs->keyBy('program_id')->get($program->id);
```

Comment: You don't need to do `$user->save()`. It is redudant

Comment: Also, it has to be `programs->where` vs `programs()->where`. Later throws error.